# Glide - download and resize GIF into a file

Tags: android, android-glide

I need to download a GIF and save it to external storage so I can send it via MMS.Messages have a limit 300kb and most of the GIFs are too large so I need to resize them.

I am using Glide in rest of my project and Glide has a nifty function which should, in theory, download a resized image. But it doesn't.

In short, here's the code I'm calling inside a background thread:

```
byte[] bytes = Glide.with(context)
                    .load(url)
                    .asGif()
                    .toBytes()
                    .into(250, 250)
                    .get();
file = new File(fileName);

FileOutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(file);
fileWriter.write(bytes);
fileWriter.flush();
fileWriter.close();
```

Downloaded files still keep their original size which is above the MMS limit of 300kb whereas they should be 250x250 pixels.

Comment: Use _override(250, 250)_ or convert `byte` to `bitmap` and resize it by your desired dimensions and save it to external storage.

Comment: override doesn't seem to do aynthing. Converting byte[] to bitmap doesn't work. It just saves it as a .png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asked the same question on Glide Github and got the answer there. Apparently Glide will only resize images that are larger than 500 x 500, unless a fitCenter() (or any other) transformation is used.

So, to resize the .gif file, use this code:

```
byte[] bytes = Glide.with(context)
                        .load(url)
                        .asGif()
                        .toBytes()
                        .transform(new GifDrawableTransformation(new CenterCrop(context), Glide.get(context).getBitmapPool()))
                        .into(250, 250)
                        .get();
```

Comment: If you don't specify a Transformation, Glide will use whatever Downsampler you set (or the default) to downsample the image. Android only supports power of 2 downsampling, which means that, without a transformation, resizing isn't precise. The default Downsampler downsamples to between the requested size and 2x the requested size. See http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/load/resource/bitmap/Downsampler.html

Comment: asGif after load() gives error cannot find symbole but before load works fine.

Comment: ok your code snippet is based on glide v3. It would be glad if you can write this for v4 as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can do compress that file also and then store in database
this link will help you. in this first convert .gif to .png then use it.
[Android - Best way to convert .gif to .png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310745/android-best-way-to-convert-gif-to-png?rq=1)

Comment: Show some snippet to OP

Comment: That doesn't help. I need a file in external storage so I can send it via MMS.