# Glide - Save GIF to File

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gif, android-glide

Sidenote - although some of my examples are in Kotlin, answers in either Java or Kotlin are helpful.

I'm creating a GIF keyboard using the [Commit Content API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard). To do this, I need to be able to create `.gif` files.

I'm using Glide to fetch the images from the internet and display them in a list inside of a `recyclerview`.

For each image Glide downloads, I have to create a `File` object with the data of that image.

I see two methods that could accomplish this objective.

1] Create a listener that overrides `onResourceReady` like so. The problem with this method is that I don't know how to convert a `GifDrawable` to a `.gif` file because all the Stack Overflow posts talk about how to convert a `Drawable` to a file:

```
    Glide.with(context)
            .asGif()
            .load(items[position])
            .listener(object : RequestListener<GifDrawable> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<GifDrawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    Log.d("VED-APP","Glide Load Failed")
                    return false
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(resource: GifDrawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<GifDrawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    //I need code to convert the GifDrawable to a File

                    return false
                }

            })
            .into(holder.imageView)
```

2] Load the image to a `ByteArray` or something similar. Example Java code, taken from the post [Glide - download and resize GIF into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129543/glide-download-and-resize-gif-into-a-file?rq=1), could look like this. The problem with this code is that

A] `.into(width,height)` is deprecated

B] there is no `.toBytes` method

C] I don't want to specify the dimensions of my GIF - I'd just like to use the original size. (Or, at the very least, I'd like to preserve the aspect ratio)

```
byte[] bytes = Glide.with(context)
                    .load(items[position])
                    .asGif()
                    .toBytes()
                    .into(250, 250)
                    .get();
file = new File(fileName);

FileOutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(file);
fileWriter.write(bytes);
fileWriter.flush();
fileWriter.close();
```

Can someone help me improve either of these two methods, or suggest a new way to convert a GIF to a file with Glide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update @Nhật Tôn's solution is probably better if you just need the URI for the content comit API.

I don't know if @Nhật Tôn's solution works. But, this is the solution I am using right now, which is based off of their solution. My solution is in Kotlin, but it can be easily converted to Java.

First, I load the image into the `ImageView` with the following code:

```
//items[position] is a string that represents a URL
Glide.with(context)
        .load(items[position])
        .into(holder.imageView)
```

Then I fetch the `GifDrawable` from the `ImageView` and write it to a `File` object.

```
val byteBuffer = (holder.imageView.drawable as GifDrawable).buffer
val gifFile = File(localDirectory, "test.gif")

val output = FileOutputStream(gifFile)
val bytes = ByteArray(byteBuffer.capacity())
(byteBuffer.duplicate().clear() as ByteBuffer).get(bytes)
output.write(bytes, 0 ,bytes.size)
output.close()
```

A potential problem with this solution is that the `GifDrawable` could be modified while it is being written to a file.

A fix to this is cloning the `GifDrawable` like so before writing it to a file:

```
val newGifDrawable = ((holder.imageView.drawable).constantState.newDrawable().mutate()) as GifDrawable
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to save all the gifs in one specific location and/or have to named the gif, I suggest you just use the gifs that Glide automatically cached for you.

So firstly, in your OnBindViewHolder method, just load the gif to your imageview as normal:

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load(items[position])
            .apply(new RequestOptions()
                    // This is to cache all versions of the gif, whether low-res or original size
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
            .into(holder.imageView);
```

And use this method to get the uri anywhere you want:

```
Glide.with(this)
            // Actually it won't download another time if the file has been cached
            .download(items[position])
            .listener(new RequestListener<File>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<File> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(File resource, Object model, Target<File> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    //Use this uri for the Commit Content API
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(resource);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .submit();
```

Comment: Would it be possible to copy the `resource` object of type `File` to another location (i.e - my app's internal storage?)

Comment: Update - I tried this code and found the file name of the `resource` object returned by Glide was: `98d8777561c28b94d88db128f9bbb768704353b40a79b52e4ac63861289fc79e.0`. My question then is, can I just write this using an `outputstream` into a GIF file?

Comment: Yes you may save the file with the name similar to  `items[position]` so it's easier for you to retrieve later. And you can add the `.listener` operator in the first code block to save the file right there, no need for another method just to download it.

Comment: can we resixe the gif. I saw codes for resizing gif for View but I want to save the file after resizing